# How to paginate logs from a Kubernetes pod?

Tags: pagination, kubernetes

I have a service that displays logs from pods running in my Kubernetes cluster. I receive them via k8s [/pods/{name}/log](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.8/#read-log) API. The logs tend to grow big so I'd like to be able to paginate the response to avoid loading them whole every time. Result similar to how [Kubernetes dashboard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#logs-viewer) displays logs would be perfect.

This dashboard however seems to solve the problem by running a separate backend service that loads the logs, chops them into pieces and prepares for the frontend to consume.

I'd like to avoid that and use only the API with its query parameters like `limitBytes` and `sinceSeconds` but those seem to be insufficient to make proper pagination work.

Does anyone have a good solution for that? Or maybe know if k8s plans to implement pagination in logs API?

Comment: Pagination for the resource lists is alpha in k8s 1.8 and will be beta in 1.9: https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/365 ; but I don't know if there are any plans for pod logs pagination.

Comment: What's wrong with `sinceSeconds`, as in my mental model that's about as cursor-esque as it gets? You may also have success with [logspout-redis](https://github.com/rtoma/logspout-redis-logstash#readme), and pop the lines out of redis just like logstash would, but perhaps with redis expiry for circumstances where no one is watching those keys